# handle flash application update

Tags: java, flash

We build a Flex/J2EE application deployed in several site. When we update the application, we warn the client, shutdown tomcat, do our stuff, and warn the client client again that he can go back to work.

For now, it's fine : BUT, some of the client forget to restart they browser. So the .swf ( the flash part ) of our application remains in the cache/memory of theire browser. So they use a up to date java application with a out dated flash UI.

Constraint : We can interact only with the server part, where tomcat run. We dont even know the IP of the client.

We are looking for a way of be certain that all flash UI are up to date. We are ready to develop something if needed, but first we look into easy solution.

our idea so far :

- A JavaScript hack to force the browser to restart
- A method in the UI to check the version of the java part. if mismatch => message who tell "restart"

Anybody with something better ?

Answer (score 3):

you can create a container that loads your flash application. The loader would retrieve a version id from the server and load an updated version of the app (app.swf?version=322).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to be able to [send an event](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/Socket.html#event:socketData) to the Client that indicates the server update has happened, and then setup the client to display a message and possibly even do an automatic page refresh after a timeout.

If your server architecture is more RESTful, then your idea of exposing a queryable interface, that the client can submit it's current version to, and trigger a refresh if there is a mismatch would be appropriate.

Either way, [navigateToURL](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29) is your friend.

Comment: indeed, navigateToUrl seems to be my friend. I will look at it.